# How to use NESTJS modules in separate classes

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

Sometimes I need to use some methods which implemented in nestjs code structure in separate from this classes

For example we have such architecture:

```
entities
   -entity.entity.ts
   -entity.module.ts
   -entity.service.ts
   -entity.providers.ts
```

So how Can I use method or property from entity.service in separate class? Such like this:

```
import EntityService from './entities.entity.service'

export class SeparateClass{
   propertyFromEntityService: string

   constructor() {
      this.propertyFromEntityService = EntityService.propertyFromEntityService
 }
}
```

And one more important point. I don’t want to implement this separate class in the nestjs structure, I just want to use it as a regular class. Thank you

Comment: How exactly is "SeparateClass" being used in your application?

Comment: Actually I use this guide https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/gateways for enabling sockets, I want to create sockets = [] property in events.gateway.ts file and use this property in the controller that send messages to client side when ended my controller method

Comment: You need to inject with dependency injection. Make your `EntityService` injectable and inject it into `SeparateClass` constructor. Look at the docs for further info. https://docs.nestjs.com/

Comment: @Naor Levi thanks ) I know that it works but I dont want to use nestjs structure for this and this case require that I include EntityService into SeparateClass module providers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not wanting to use dependency injection via Nest, but you still want to use a property from a class in the Nest application, you'll need to manually instantiate the class, providing whatever dependencies that class has, and then pulling the property from the service. The other option, if this class will be used outside of the Nest context, but still while the Nest application is running, is you can use the Nest application to get the service via `app.get(EntityService)`, but this does require you to have access to `app` after the `NestFactory` has created the application.